# How to get progress information inside a range based for loop?

Tags: java

I have a very long running for loop and I would like to print out some progress information.

With a normal for loop this is easy, since you can divide the loop-variable by the maximum to get a progress indicator, i.e. do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<container.size(); i++) {
  if(i%10==0) System.out.println("Progress " +  Double.toString(i/container.size()*100.0) + "%.")
}
```

Is there a way to do something like this without adding a counter variable (which somehow defeats the purpose of the range based for loop)?

```
//... Foreach loop over all elements in arr.
for (type var : arr) {
    body-of-loop
    // print progress info here?
}
```

Comment: why not every iteration ?

Comment: @Mritunjay too much text

Comment: @Berger I don't think so, because I do not require the actual index - any other means of getting approximate progress information would be sufficient as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the core of the question: You cannot derive any progress information from a range-based `for`-loop. Mainly because there may not be any. You could easily create an `Iterable` for which

```
for (T t : iterable) {
    ...
}
```

is an infinite loop. You *have* to know the number of elements that you're iterating over.

---

The solution may then depend on the type of the container. If it is a `List`, then you could use the indexed access

```
for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    if (i%10==0) System.out.println("Step "+i+" of "+list.size());

    T t = list.get(i);
    doSomethingWith(t);
}
```

Otherwise, you'll probably have to introduce a counter variable:

```
int step = 0;
for (T t : set) {
    if (step%10==0) System.out.println("Step "+step+" of "+set.size());

    doSomethingWith(t);
}
```

---

From a more high-level point of view: I'd **strongly** recommend to think about whether you don't need to generalize this kind of progress information. If this is not only intended for debugging, then you should/could at least extract it into a function:

```
int step = 0;
for (T t : set) {
    reportProgress(step, set.size());

    doSomethingWith(t);
}

private static void reportProgress(int step, int total) {
    if (step%10==0) System.out.println("Step "+step+" of "+total);
}
```

Even more generic could be to use a (functional) interface, like

```
interface ProgressReporter {
    void reportProgress(String message, int step, int total);
}

// Using it:
int step = 0;
for (T t : set) {
    progressReporter.reportProgress("My loop", step, set.size());

    doSomethingWith(t);
}
```

This allows you, for example, to show the progress in a `ProgressBar` in the future, redirecting the progress to a `Logger`, or changing the report interval (e.g. from `step%10` to `step%100` or `step%(total/10+1)` generically.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems,

- an `int / int` is an `int` e.g. 5 / 10 = 0 (with 5 remainder)
- the format will print 16 digits of accuracy which will look ugly.

I suggest you try

```
for (int i = 0; i < container.size(); i++) {
   if (i % 10 == 0) 
       System.out.printf("Progress %.1f%%\n", 100.0 * i / container.size());
}
```

By multiplying the `100.0 *` first the number becomes a `double` so when you do the division it is a floating point number.

You could also adjust the fraction

```
int logEvery = Math.max(10, container.size() / 100);
for (int i = 0; i < container.size(); i++) {
   if (i % logEvery == 0) 
       System.out.println("Progress " + 100 * i / container.size() + "%");
}
```

This doesn't use floating point but by multiply by 100 first the number you are not discarding the portion done.

You can use a combination of integer and floating point

```
int logEvery = Math.max(10, container.size() / 1000);
for (int i = 0; i < container.size(); i++) {
   if (i % logEvery == 0) 
       System.out.println("Progress " + 1000 * i / container.size() / 10.0 + "%");
}
```

By multiplying by 1000 and dividing by 10.0, you get a percentage but with one decimal place.